# Using variables(int/string) to define frame/object names

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, jinternalframe

I have an array of frames and a button that when clicked, will add a new frame to the array.

I'm wondering if I can use the length of the array to determine the name of the new frame to add. For example, if the length of the array is 8, I store this in a variable (for example, int i = length, which is 8).

I then create the frame with i, so

```
InternalFrame intFrame(i) = new InternalFrame();
intFrameArray.add(intFrame(i));
```

is using intFrame(i) the correct way to do this? I'm currently not able to test myself as I'm at work but I have had a few problems attempting this last night.

Comment: Why do you want to name the variable reference? Since you are going to add the object to the array anyway?

Comment: @Codebender I want to be able to create new frames dynamically while the code is running. The frames act as rooms in a hostel booking software im making to learn java. I want the user to be able to add extra rooms, using an array and getting the length of the array was the best way I thought of knowing how many frames to have and keep everything in order. Im open to suggestion though, im struggling a little.

Comment: Is InternalFrame  a your custom object?

Comment: @Renjith Is it supposed to be JInternalFrame? Its not custom I dont think.

Comment: @ChrisCollins, You don't need to create different variables for that. different objects will do. Everytime, just do `intFrame = new InternalFrame()` and then add it to array. You don't need `intFrame1`, `intFrame2` ...

Comment: For creating rooms dynamically on press of a button, you can create a new frame like this InternalFrame intFrame = new InternalFrame(); and add it to your arraylist.
intFrameArray.add(intFrame);

Comment: And whenever you nee to find how many rooms are there, you can call size() on the arraylist.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a Room class? Where in clicking the '+' button I can create a new class rather than the messy way I am currently doing?

Answer (score 1):

> is using intFrame(i) the correct way to do this?

No. You can't. Java won't let you do that. **Variable name cannot be dynamic.**

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to create an internalFrame like I want? Using an integer to dictate the name. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisCollins No. It is not. It should be static. variable name cannot be dynamic. Please let us know, what you want to do with that later ?

Comment: The frames act as rooms in a hostel booking software I am making to learn java. I want the user to be able to add or remove rooms  by clicking a (+room) or (-room) button. I cant figure out how to write code that lets me create any number of frames while the code is running, its proving tricky.